# How to get Nice-Looking URLS - Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I have been looking around the web for a way to get the URL that is like:

`example.com/games/game1` instead of `example.com/games?id=game1`

I have looked around the Node.JS website but I couldn't find anything that seemed to apply to my situation.
Any help is very appreciated. I have found an answer that did this using a .HTACCESS file, but I couldn't find a node.js alternative. The question/answer that I found was, [creating nice looking URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661270/creating-nice-looking-urls)

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067230/jade-url-routing-in-node-express

Comment: Also, this "design pattern" is called REST and you're trying to do RESTful URLs.

Comment: @limelights Not necessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list to all requests, then parse `request.url` to decide which page to render or whether to return a 404 / 302 or whatever you want to do. This is just a small example. You probably want to separate your routing from your logic:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var parts = request.url.split('/');
    if(parts[0] === 'games'){
        var id = parts[1];
        // Check if valid id
        // And render the correct page
    }
}).listen(80);
```

Answer (score 1):

This URL `example.com/games?id=game1` is passing the id as a GET parameter. To replace it with `example.com/games/game1`, you just have to come with a strategy on how to pass this id. This strategy is usually referred to `node.js` as routes, and, they are plenty of options on how to achieve your goal:

- If you are using Express framework, you have built in ability to do stuff like this (based off [TJ Holowaychuk's route separation examples](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/route-separation)):

`app.get('/games/:id', games.view);`

Then, in your game.js file:

```
exports.view = function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params.id); //gives you game1
  //...
};
```

- Another way to do it is to use something specific for routing (instead of a whole framework). [Director](https://github.com/flatiron/director) comes to mind.

```
var viewGame = function(gameId) { console.log(gameId); };

var routes = {
  '/games/:gameId': viewGame
};
```